# On the topology of the space of entire functions.

Tags: entire-functions

I have a doubt. When we have a Banach space $X$, by definition, each element $f$ in $X$ has a norm $\left\|f\right\|_X$. On the other hand, I understand that the space of entire functions $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}):=H$ is not a Banach space but if it is a Frechet space and the topology obtained is the one obtained from the norms $\left\|f\right\|_K:=sup_{z\in K}|f(z)|$ with $K$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to define $\left\|f\right\|_H$ in some way? I mean if $\left\|f\right\|_H=sup_{z\in K}|f(z)|$ for some $K$ compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$?
(I can't understand this concept)
Thank you.

Comment: I would like to prove that the operator $M_z$ multiplication by $z$, $M_z:H\to H$ is bounded, that is, that $\left\|M_z f(z)\right\|_{H}=\left\|zf(z)\right\|_{H}\leq C \left\|f\right\|_H$

The same for the differentiation operator $\partial_z$, which is bounded. My goal is to try to understand what it means for an operator to be limited between these spaces with those rules.